# To read file line by line, store in dictionary as dict[key1][key2] =value in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract data from a file with 3 columns:

```
Region, Range, Population 
Scotland, 1, 10000 
Glasgow, 14, 5000 
Edinburgh, 15, 4000
```

The code:

```
file = open(self.file_name, encoding="iso-8859-1")
reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for line in reader:
            region=line["Region"]
            range=line['Range']
            population=line['Population']
            #self.data_dict[region,range] = population
```

I would like to store the total population per range and region in dictionary self.data_dict with such structure: data_dict[region][range] corresponds to the population.

For example, data_dict["Region1"]["1"] should contain the number of children that are one year old in the
region "Region1".
Would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected output, given the input above?

Comment: Hello Hai Vu, I suppose as an output I expect the data_dict to be like this dict={'Scotland':{'1':'10000'},'Glasgow':{'14':'500'} , 'Edinburgh':{'15':'4000'}}

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a terrible way to store your data but...

```
with open(self.file_name, encoding='iso-8859-1') as f:
    self.data_dict = {x['Region']:{x['Range']:x['Population']} for x in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)}

print(self.data_dict['Scotland']['1'])
```

Output:

```
10000
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think you right that I need to use nested dictionary for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```py
import csv
import json

data_dict = {}
with open("population.csv", "r", encoding="iso-8859-1") as stream:
    next(stream)  # Skip the headers
    reader = csv.reader(stream, skipinitialspace=True)
    for region, age_range, population in reader:
        data_dict.setdefault(region, {})[age_range] = int(population)
```

At this point, `data_dict` is:

```
{
    "Scotland": {
        "1": 10000
    },
    "Glasgow": {
        "14": 5000
    },
    "Edinburgh": {
        "15": 4000
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- I use `csv.reader` instead of `csv.DictReader` because the former is easier to work with
- `data_dict.setdefault(region, {})` is a shorthand for

  ```
    if region not in data_dict:
        data_dict[region] = {}
  ```
- I also converted the population from a string to a number